# Correct property name for nested property and INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm using the INotifyDataError interface for async validation in WPF. I have a property

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="5" 
         Text="{Binding XXX.Name, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
```

On my view model  I have a property

```
public SomeType XXX
```

and on the type SomeType I have the property

```
public string Name
```

now my ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataError and validation is done asynchronously in my viewmodel class. SomeType only implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

My questions is this. When I raise `ErrorsChanged` event with `DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName))` what should the propertyName be. Note my Binding path is `XXX.Name`. Should propertyName be

- XXX.Name
- Name

or something else or do I have to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in my `SomeType` class as well which I was hoping not to have to do as I want my validation to stay in the main view model.

Anyway I've tried both above and the textbox is not getting a red box around it though I can verify that the error event is being raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik i would say you have to implement IDataErrorInfo for your property XXX in your SomeType class because you bind to it. i do this in my projects and it works.

Comment: But what if it is a class you can't implement INotifyDataErrorInfo for. For arguments sake let's say the standard ``Point`` class. If I have an individual text box for the ``X`` and the ``Y`` fields respectively how would I provide validation feedback via INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Comment: create a wrapper class?